# image centering not working with margin:0 auto

Tags: css

```
<div class="imgw">
    <img src="http://placehold.it/100x100"/>
</div>

.imgw{
    margin: 0 auto 0 auto;
}

img{
    margin: 0 auto 0 auto;
}
```

not working with text-align, tested. I tried even to ply to the img element itself, not working.

Answer (score 4):

`margin:0 auto` works on block elements.

Try:

```
.imgw img{
    display:block;
    margin: 0 auto;
}
```

[**DEMO here.**](http://jsfiddle.net/rH6wv/1)

Comment: @Era No you don't -- and even this is a better solution so +1 but just make sure you use a `class` or atleast `.imgw img {}` else your selector will make all the images to block level

Answer (score 2):

`text-align: center;` will work. I have shown an example below.

### HTML:

```
<div class="imgw">
    <img src="http://placehold.it/100x100" />
</div>
```

### CSS:

```
.imgw {
    text-align: center;
}
```

[**DEMO HERE**](http://jsfiddle.net/Ruddy/f44G6/)

Comment: Well, +1 but this will be efficient only when there is ONLY image inside the `div` else OP will have to nest the text inside another element with `text-align` set to left

Answer (score 1):

This is what I did to center align a map in a div.

```
.map{
  display: block;
  margin-right: auto;
  margin-left: auto;
}
```

HTML structure:

```
<div class='item-detail cf'>
    <img alt='Google Map' class='map' src= "some_url">
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Ammend your css to :

```
.imgw{
    width:96%; /* to give some width, is helpful in centering*/
    margin: 0 auto; /* this should do */
}

.imgw > img{
    margin: 0 auto;
}
```